# A* Algorithm System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, a-star

```
public List<Location2D> Path(Location2D start, Location2D goal)
{
    openset = new List<NodeInfo>(); // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node.
    closedset = new List<NodeInfo>(); // The set of nodes already evaluated.
    path = new List<Location2D>(); // The path result.
    came_from = new Dictionary<Location2D, Location2D>();

    NodeInfo Start = new NodeInfo();
    Start.SetLoction(start.X, start.Y);
    Start.H = GetHValue(start, goal);
    openset.Add(Start);

    while (openset.Count > 0) { // while openset is not empty
        NodeInfo current = CheckBestNode(); //the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value

        if (current.Location.Equals(goal)) {
            ReconstructPathRecursive(current.Location);
            return path;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // neighbor nodes.
            NodeInfo neighbor = new NodeInfo();
            neighbor.SetLoction((ushort)(current.Location.X + ArrayX[i]), (ushort)(current.Location.Y + ArrayY[i]));

            bool tentative_is_better = false;

            if (closedset.Contains(neighbor))
                continue;
            if (!map.Cells[neighbor.Location.X, neighbor.Location.Y].Walkable) { closedset.Add(neighbor); continue; }

            Double tentative_g_score = current.G + DistanceBetween(current.Location, neighbor.Location);

            if (!openset.Contains(neighbor)) {
                openset.Add(neighbor);
                neighbor.H = GetHValue(neighbor.Location, goal);
                tentative_is_better = true;
            } else if (tentative_g_score < neighbor.G) {
                tentative_is_better = true;
            } else {
                tentative_is_better = false;
            }

            if (tentative_is_better) {
                came_from[neighbor.Location] = current.Location;
                neighbor.G = tentative_g_score;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void ReconstructPathRecursive(Location2D current_node)
{
    Location2D temp;
    if (came_from.TryGetValue(current_node, out temp)) {
        path.Add(temp);
        ReconstructPathRecursive(temp);
    } else {
        path.Add(current_node);
    }
}
```

so am Implementing A* Algorithm and when it find the Goal it goes to the  `ReconstructPathRecursive` 
and then the app crash and throw this exception `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

and `This thread is stopped with only external code frames on the call stack. External code frames are typically from framework code but can also include other optimized modules which are loaded in the target process.`

idk what's wrong!

Comment: Likely infinite recursion somewhere, check your base cases.

Comment: Does `came_from.TryGetValue(current_node, out temp))` always return true? If so, you certainly have a stack overflow. Check if you have loops in your path.

Comment: The cause of your infinite recursion could be a cycle in your graph; you can probably identify the problem very quickly by stepping through the code with the debugger.

Comment: The ReconstructPathRecursive method seems rather straight forward. Add some debug statements, like print number of recursions, or even better - print the path that ReconstructPathRecursive walks through. Start with a small test case, and you'll find the recursion loop eating your stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `NodeInfo Parent {get; set; }` as a filed inside the `NodeInfo` class, and I add new `List<NodeInfo>` called `Nodes` when tentative is better :-

```
if (tentative_is_better) {
                        neighbor.Parent = current;
                        nodes.Add(neighbor);
                        neighbor.G = tentative_g_score;
                    }
```

then when it finds the goal :-

```
if (current.Location.Equals(goal)){
                    ReconstructPath(current);
                    path.Reverse();
                    return path;
                }
```

where `ReconstructPath` :-

```
private void ReconstructPath(NodeInfo current) {
            if (current.Parent == null) return;
            path.Add(current.Parent.Location);
            ReconstructPath(current.Parent);
        }
```

and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have to be recursive, because it's tail recursive. So you can rewrite it like this:

```
private void ReconstructPathIterative(Location2D current_node)
{
    Location2D temp;
    while (came_from.TryGetValue(current_node, out temp))
    {
        path.Add(temp);
        current_node = temp;
    }
    path.Add(current_node);
}
```

That only helps if the path was simply too long to fit on the stack, not if it was infinite.

Comment: 1st it take lots of time and CPU usage then it break and throw the same exception the path was having like 500k elements inside of it!

Comment: @MixedCoder this code can not possibly throw a StackOverflowException on its own, since it only uses a constant small amount of stack space. It should handle 500k nodes no problem. Is path.Add broken?

Comment: it's like an endless loop keeps adding to path , here is a pic to show you the error http://i44.tinypic.com/20zd66f.jpg

Comment: @MixedCoder that's a very different error - and 67m is quite different from 500k. Indeed it looks like the path itself is broken and loops. Could be an error in Closed set maintaining/testing. Or perhaps of parent-updating.

Comment: thnx for your time , I have fixed it :)